# Accessing values from UserControl in converter in MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an application, where I have a main window and one dialogbox. In my main window I have a listbox of objects with two properties: Name and Type. My dialog box is used to add new elements to the listbox. I've created a dialogbox as a UserControl and use it as a WindowContent for my dialogbox. I open dialog using a command attached to a button. If a result of dialogbox returns true, than I would like to add new element to listbox. This is done with command with parameter and command parameter is created using multivalue converter. Here is the question:

How can I access properties, which are created in usercontrol, in my converter.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<vu:CustomContentDialogBox x:Name="AddCriterionDialogBox" Caption="Add criterion" WindowWidth="400" 
                           WindowHeight="150" CommandTrue="{Binding Path=CriteriaViewModel.AddCriterionCommand}">
    <vu:CustomContentDialogBox.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource criterionConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Name" />
            <Binding Path="Type" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </vu:CustomContentDialogBox.CommandParameter>
    <vu:CustomContentDialogBox.WindowContent>
        <uc:AddCriterionUserControl />
    </vu:CustomContentDialogBox.WindowContent>
</vu:CustomContentDialogBox>
<Button ToolBar.OverflowMode="Never" Style="{DynamicResource btn_Remove_png}"
        Command="{Binding ElementName=AddCriterionDialogBox, Path=ShowCommand}" />
```

AddCriterionUserControl.xaml

```
<Grid>
        <TextBox Name="tbName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
        <ComboBox Name="cbCriterionType" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Gain" IsSelected="True" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Cost" />
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="60" Height="24" Margin="0,0,10,7" 
                Content="Add" vu:CustomContentDialogBox.CustomContentDialogResult="True"/>
</Grid>
```

I need to access values `tbName` and `cbCriterionType` from usercontrol in my converter to be able to create a new object using command `CriteriaViewModel.AddCriterionCommand`. Should I use DependencyProperty? I try to follow MVVM rules.

Comment: DependencyProperty is only i can suggest. Dp is not violation of any mvvm rules

Comment: What prevents you from giving the dialog box its own view model and bind `Name` and `Type` to properties therein, and then make the command (also moved to the dialog's view model) use those properties?

Comment: Set the `DataContext` of the `AddCriterionUserControl` to the object where `Name` and `Types` properies are defined and bind to them as usual in your XAML. The you can simply access these properties in the `Execute` method of the `AddCriterionCommand`.

Comment: I want to use my CustomContentDialogBox class, beacuse this is a class, where I will be creating all my dialogboxes, so I think, that I can't move command somewhere else. I am pretty new in wpf and xaml and I am still learning. CommandTrue property is used when dialogbox is finished ok, but I have also CommandFalse and CommandNull. Using converter in this scenario is wrong?